# Is there a Tortoise SVN analogue to Perforce's "File Synced to Previous Revision" icon

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, perforce

We have some developers here that aren't watching the logs to look for potential conflicts before attempting commits or doing SVN updates successfully. Perforce had the super friendly "File Synced to Previous Revision" [icon](http://ftp.perforce.com/pub/perforce/r14.1/doc/help/p4v/en/About_file_icons.html) that gave you the heads up that you're out of sync with the repository. Is there any sort of similar feature to likewise get a heads up? Even one triggered manually would be acceptable, I'll take that over nothing.

[image: Perforce Icon set]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I know to do it via Tortoise is to use the [Check for Modifications dialog](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html#tsvn-dug-wcstatus-2), and click the "Check Repository" button:

[image: Check for Modifications dialog]

If the file in the repository has been modified since you last updated your working copy, the "Remote text status" column will read "modified."